# Using CoreBluetooth is it possible to get the raw scan record of a Bluetooth LE device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I'm trying to get a better understanding of Bluetooth LE and been playing around with both iOS and Android's bluetooth stacks and various beacons (StickNFind, Estimote etc...)

- On Android, when a device is discovered I get a raw "scan record" - a blob of data that I can parse myself to get the device's advertised data.
- On iOS, this is parsed by iOS and presented as a dictionary.

Fair enough, except I was trying to use CoreBluetooth (ie: not location services) to read the advertisement data from an iBeacon and noticed that iOS seems to strip out the manufacturer specific advertisement data for iBeacon devices.

I realise I should probably be using Apple sanctioned ways for detecting iBeacons but it doesn't really fit our use case and wondering if there's a way around it.

Comment: take a look at this http://beekn.net/2013/10/ibeacons-can-my-ios-app-find-beacons-that-arent-mine/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: iOS does let you access the raw data for any Bluetooth advertisement that does not match the iBeacon format.**

Unfortunately, iOS blocks access to the raw data of all BLE advertisements<strike>, including those</strike> of iBeacons. This makes it impossible to access the iBeacon identifiers with `CoreBluetooth`.

See details in [this blog post](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html).

Comment: This is ONLY true for iBeacons. You can indeed obtain the raw advertisement data for any other LE advertisement on iOS: `[advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]`

Comment: You are correct.  I did not know this when I posted the answer.  I will clarify.